# Dynamic email creation and reply to post via email

Tags: php, email

I would like to create an application in php, which can create dynamic emails for users (someting like username.123@domain.com) as evernote, facebook etc.

This can also provide the users a feature to reply to post via created email address (username.123@domain.com). Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how Evernote and facebook doing this. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using cpanel then you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112589/php-cpanel-is-there-a-way-to-get-total-size-of-all-emails-on-a-users-account/20112939#20112939

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement a feature: Post to a forum via email?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439240/how-to-implement-a-feature-post-to-a-forum-via-email). Also worth checking: [Creating email address via PHP or any other script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933811/)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to setup a mail server on the host machine, which listens to a catch-all email address, and pipes the incoming emails to a PHP script. The PHP script would then interpret the emails. Generally the subject of the email would contain a unique identifier code which the script can use to work out which post the reply is for.

Comment: I read posts about catch-all address, some says it will give as lot of spam issues. What you think ?

Comment: You would simply configure the script to ignore any emails to addresses which aren't known to the system.